# Plat former Game - A realistic path-finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, path-finding

I am making a game and i have come across a hard part to implement into code. My game is a tile-bases platformer with lots of enemies chasing you. basically, in theory, I want my enemies to be able to, every frame/second/2 seconds, find the realistic, and shortest path to my player. I originally thought of A-star as a solution, but it leads the enemies to paths that defy gravity, which is not good. Also, multiple enemies will be using it every second to get the latest path, and then walk the first few tiles of it. So they will be discarding the rest of the path every second, and just following the first few tiles of it. I know this seems like a lot, to calculate a new path every second, all at the same time, if their is more than one enemy, but I don't know any other way to achieve what i want.
This is a picture of what I want: [image: picture]
Explanation: The green figure is the player, the red one is an enemy. the grey tiles are regular, open, nothing there tiles, the brown tiles being ones that you can stand on. And finally the highlighted yellow tiles represents the path that i want my enemy to be able to find, in order to realistically get to the player.
SO, the question is: What realistic path-finding algorithm can i use to acquire this? While keeping it fast?

EDIT*
I updated the picture to represent the most complicated map that their could be. this map represents what the player of my game actually sees, they just use WASD and can move around and they see themselves move through this 2d plat-former view. Their will be different types of enemies, all with different speeds and jump heights. but all will have enough jump height and speed to make the jumps in this map, and maneuver through it. The maps are generated by simply reading an XML file that has the level data in it. the data is then parsed and different types of tiles are placed in the tile holding sprite, acording to what the XML says. EX( XML node: (type="reg" graphic="grass2" x="5" y="7") and so the x and y are multiplied by the constant gridSize (like 30 or something) and they are placed down accordingly. The enemies get their frame-by-frame instruction from an AI class attached to them. This class is responsible for producing this path and return the first direction to the enemy, this should only happen every second or so, so that the enemies don't follow a old, wrong path. Please let me know if you understand my concept, and you have some thought/ideas or maybe even the answer that i'm looking for.
ALSO: the physics in this game is separate from the pathfinding, they work just fine, using a AABB vs AABB concept (the player and enemies also being AABBs).

Comment: @Cœur thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Apparently now I can see the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The trick with using A* here is how you link tiles together to form available paths. Take for example the first gap the red player would need to cross.  The 'link' to the next platform (aka brown tile to the left) is actually a jump action, not a move action. Additionally, it's up to you to determine how the nodes connect together; I'd add a heavy penalty when moving from a gray tile over a brown tile to a gray tile with nothing underneath just for starters (without discouraging jumps that open a shortcut).

There are two routes I see personally: running a quick prediction of how far the player can jump and where they'd jump and adjusting how the algorithm determines node adjacency or accept the path and determine when parts of the path "hang" in the air (no brown tile immediately below) and animate the enemy 'jumping' to the next part of the path. The trick is handling things when the enemy may pass through brown tiles in the even the path isn't a parabola.

I am not versed in either solution; just something I've thought about.

Comment: Interesting... but how could my code tell between a part where the enemy needs to jump and going straight up? And the idea of weighing tiles that have no brown tiles below it, fits into this. But yeah, you have given me a few ideas that i will definitely try to implement and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us the most complicated case of map, player and enemy behaviour (including jumping up and across speed)  that you are going to either automatically create or manually create so we can give relevant advice. The given map is so simple, put the map in an 2-dimensional array and then the initial player location as an element of that map and then first test whether lower number column on the same row is occupied by brown if not put player there and repeat until false then same row higher column and so on to move enemy.

Update: from my reading of the stage generation- its sometime you create- not semi-random.

My suggestion is the enemy creates clones of itself with its same AI but invisible and each clone  starts going in different direction jump up/left/right/jump diagonal right/left and every time it succeeds it creates a new clone- basically a genetic algorithm. From the map it seems an enemy never need to evaluate one path over another just one way fails to get closer to the player's initial position and other doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't quite understand your last sentence. Do you mean scan the row that the enemy is in for the first occurrence of a brown tile, then repeat for every column above and below it? I can see how it does seem like it could work for this map, but i'm talking about any map. Like for example if just a wall separated the player and the enemy, and there was a huge maze to go though, how would the enemy find the path to the player, while obeying the laws of physics.

Comment: Yes-but read my first query- we need a picture of the  most complicated map (and how it would be generated and whether its side or top view), some description of the controls of the player and some description of the AI of intended enemies (i.e. do  they travel at different speeds going up and down.